# How to form an if statement to choose one of several dictionaries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, dictionary

I need to plug key values into an equation. Those values need to come from one dictionary or another based on the position of a segmented control.

Here is the code for the segmented control:

```
- (IBAction)tankChooser:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    if (_tankControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==0)
    {
        bigTank = YES;
        tankType = @"dragon500";
    }
    if (_tankControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==1)
    {
        bigTank = NO;
        tankType = @"skid250";
    }
    if (_tankControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==1)
    {
        bigTank = YES;
        tankType = @"hyTech500";
    }
}
```

This is what I have been using for using the single dictionary, and it works perfectly.

```
- (void)calculateRate
    {
    NSString *dragonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dragonBarrelChart" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dragonBarrelChart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: dragonPath];

NSString *startKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.startLevel.text, startFractions];

    NSString *startValue = dragonBarrelChart[startKey];
```

Essentially, I need a way to make it so that when the user chooses a button on the segmented control, it causes NSString *startvalue to get its key/value from a different dictionary, like this one here:

```
    NSString *hyTechPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hyTechBarrelChart" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *hyTechBarrelChart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: hyTechPath];
```

If I can provide any more info, please advise. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, your goal is to retrieve the "Chart" data from a plist file which corresponds to the type of tank selected by the user. One way to do this would be to save the name of the resource in an instance variable which calculateRate would then use to retrieve the correct dictionary. Your tankChooser method would look something like this.

```
- (IBAction)tankChooser:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    if (_tankControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==0)
    {
        bigTank = YES;
        tankType = @"dragon500";
        tankResource = @"dragonBarrelChart";
    }
    if (_tankControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==1)
    {
        bigTank = NO;
        tankType = @"skid250";
        tankResource = @"skidBarrelChart";
    }
    if (_tankControl.selectedSegmentIndex ==2)//assuming you meant 2 here
    {
        bigTank = YES;
        tankType = @"hyTech500";
        tankResource = @"skidBarrelChart";
    }
}
```

Then in the rate calculator method:

```
- (void)calculateRate
{
    NSString *tankPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:tankResource ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *tankBarrelChart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: tankPath];
    //and then use this to get startValue.
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm. Interesting. I would have thought it would key off of the tankType variable. Going to go give this a shot.

Comment: That would also be a good way to do it, if you don't want to bother with another variable. You'd have to either rename your plist files, or get the filenames from tankType using a string formatter.